# How to break a DNA sequence into triplets?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I am trying to break the DNA sequence into triplets

sequence = "ATCGCCACCATCGCG"

desired output = ['ATC', GCC' 'ACC']

Not quite sure how would I do that?

Comment: A string is a sequence, so the same techniques used to split up a list will work.

Comment: [sequence[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(sequence), 3)]